# Why do I get an empty JSON

Tags: php, json

Here in my code everything works fine but the last statement seems to be wrong. It sends back an empty JSON-stream. I debugged and tried error handling on the statements but everything is fine (I removed error handling for better reading) I searched a lot and I found a lot but either I'm to stupid to use google or there is no help for my specific question (could bet, first one is correct but please don't be angry with me :-))

My Code is

```
function getMyClass() {
    global $con;
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    $json = json_decode($_POST['myClass'], false);
    $klasseId = $json->{'klassenID'};
    $statement = $con->prepare("SELECT a.SchuelerId, Nachname, Vorname, Geburtsdatum FROM schuelerklasse AS a JOIN schueler AS b ON a.SchuelerId=b.SchuelerId WHERE a.KlassenId=?");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $klasseId);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: are you sure that the query finds some rows? run in phpMyAdmin to verify

Comment: Some versions of JSON do not support date fields, on this cases you have to format those fields to a valid string.

Comment: Does `var_dump($rows)` give you anything…?

Comment: What is the collation of your database? latin1? If thats the case and you have any german umlauts in your result set json_encode won't work because it expects every value to be utf8.

Comment: @MikeAguilar `mysqli` returns date fields as strings.

Comment: Akam: Yes in phpMyAdmin this query gives an answer. Deceze: Yes but only if I do a var_dump($rows) in the while-loop. Thats a bit strange -.-*; Benjamin my Database is utf8

Comment: Wat? Only if you var_dump inside the loop? After the loop the variable is empty‽

Comment: Okay I now had the chance to try. If I do a var_dump IN or OUT the loop i got a result. If I do the print json_encode IN the loop I get a result but it is not valid. If I do the print json_encode OUT the loop I get NO result. It is empty... I only get "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution.
The Database is utf8-coded and the application is utf8-coded but the JSON-String does not accept ä ö ü and ß.
But the strange thing (for me) is that if I had put the json_encode IN the while loop I got a result. That was not valid json but it transfered ä, ö, ü and ß. Okay the problem is solved.

Thanks to all who tried to help me.

best regards

Matthias